# How to take the following input in C++

Tags: c++, iostream

I have to take variable number of double values and then a character to end the input of the double values (being read into inData list). After this i have to take input of 2 integers into i and m.

The problem is that the cin is overflowing.

i have to take following input to a program

```
0.594
0.928
0.515
0.055
0.507
0.351
0.262
0.797
0.788
0.442
0.097
0.798
0.227
0.127
0.474
0.825
0.007
0.182
0.929
0.852
e
2 5
```

For this my code is like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{    list <double> inData;
     double temp;
     int i, m, M, N;
     char a;
     while (cin >> temp)
     {    inData.push_back(temp);
     }
     N = inData.size();
     //fflush(cin);
     //cin >> a;
     cin.ignore(1);
     cin >> i >> m;
     cout << (int )a << " " << N << " " << i <<  " ABC " << m << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

What is wrong in this.. please see why is it not taking the value of i and m. i and m are giving garbage values in the cout line...

Output is coming to be

```
-65 20 233304 ABC 213344
```

where 1st, 3rd, and 5th values are garbage.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cin.clear();
cin >> a;
```

Comment: @Saurajeet -- Please upvote all of the answers that you found useful (click the up-arrow image) and accept the answer that you found most useful (click the check-mark image).

Answer (score 2):

When `cin >> temp` finally fails (because the "e" marker is encountered), the `failbit` will be set on `cin`, which prevents reading any more data from the stream until it is `clear`ed.

```
while (cin >> temp) { inData.push_back(temp); }
N = inData.size();
cin.clear(); // <---
cin >> a >> i >> m; // no need to 'ignore' or flush anything
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
     do{
        cin >> temp;     
        if (cin.good())
            inData.push_back(temp);
     } while (cin.good());
     cin.clear();
```

instead of the while loop.

The `a` variable isn't read into from `cin` anymore so will most likely be garbage.

Comment: can be simplified to just `while (cin >> temp) inData.push_back(temp); cin.clear();`

Comment: Ah! Now I see. I didn't know about `operator void*` in `istream` and kept wondering why it even works.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the line

```
    N = inData.size();
```

cin has been in a invalid status.Any operations to cin would fails. you should reset its stauts and keek using it.